# Android sensors port cant laucnh app

Tags: java, android

I can't launch my program on Android, get the error shown below:

eclipse version, i also have the newest sdk.

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2011.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://eclipse.org/

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation http://apache.org/
```

error messages:

```
[2012-02-06 18:06:15 - HelloAndroid2] ------------------------------
[2012-02-06 18:06:16 - HelloAndroid2] Android Launch!
[2012-02-06 18:06:16 - HelloAndroid2] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-06 18:06:16 - HelloAndroid2] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid2 activity launch
[2012-02-06 18:06:16 - HelloAndroid2] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'test1'
[2012-02-06 18:06:16 - HelloAndroid2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'test1'
[2012-02-06 18:06:38 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2012-02-06 18:06:38 - HelloAndroid2] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-02-06 18:06:38 - HelloAndroid2] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...





[2012-02-06 18:18:30 - HelloAndroid2] Uploading HelloAndroid2.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-02-06 18:18:30 - HelloAndroid2] Installing HelloAndroid2.apk...
[2012-02-06 18:21:09 - HelloAndroid2] Failed to install HelloAndroid2.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-02-06 18:21:09 - HelloAndroid2] (null)
[2012-02-06 18:21:10 - HelloAndroid2] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the last time there are a lot of questions that refer to the unusual behavior of Android SDK. Usually the problem is that people install new version of JDK - JDK 7.

Android SDK supports only JDK 5 and JDK 6. Please, check this!